# VBA to read image directly from word document for Base64 Conversion

Tags: image, vba, excel, base64, ms-word

Basically I have a document with lots of small images and I need a fast way to build a list of unique images (and identify them in the document), I was thinking of using Base64 conversion to store each unique image in an xml file (or simply store the MD5 hash of each image).

If the images were saved as files somewhere (i.e outside of the document) I'd be able to do this but (unless there's good reason not to) I'd like to learn how to read the image directly from the document.

Specifically, if I have `myDoc.InlineShapes(myImageIndex)` how can I most efficiently PREPARE that to either convert to Base64 or create a hash?

All the examples I can find assume the image is loaded from file, I'm hoping to load the image directly from the document... (e.g. [Convert image (jpg) to base64 in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043393/convert-image-jpg-to-base64-in-excel-vba))

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Just found this (which looks like half of the puzzle): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795440 so will have a look and post back...