How to customize a button's icon using with idMso in vsto add-in C#?
I have created a VSTO Add-in project in C# (Office Word). I want to create a ribbon (XML) that runs built-in idMso commands, but I would add a customized icon for the ribbon controls.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load" loadImage="Ribbon_LoadImage">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" getLabel="GetTab" insertBeforeMso="TabInsert">
                <group id="customGroup1" label="Drawing tools">
                    <toggleButton idMso="InkHighlighter" image="HighlighterBgImage.png" visible="true" size="large" />

To the Resources folder i added the file "HighlighterBgImage.png". But regardless, the icon corresponding to the highlighter's idMso is displayed. What should I do differently?

Have a look at, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21543037/how-can-i-add-the-images-to-button-using-the-ribbon-xml and for a related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686125/how-to-embed-images-in-office-file-for-custom-ribbon . Pretty sure there are other similar Q/As out there.

But none of them are using idMso. The reason for the difficulty is that idMso has a default icon that I could not find a solution for how to override it.

Yes, AFAIK the idea of IdMso is that when you use it, the control has the same appearance as the builtin control with that Id. see, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/f2bf1b5d-0492-46a4-88f7-dc1a9528f755 "When an existing control is cloned, its non-location-specific properties, such as the icon and label, are copied to the clone. Location-specific properties, such as the size and visibility of the control, are not copied. These properties can be set by specifying additional attributes on the control element." (my emphasis).

I've seen the getImage callback in the documentation, but no matter how I try to override it, it doesn't change the default icon. My question is slightly different to the community: can an icon belonging to idMso be overidden? It should be based on the documentation for the xml part, but I can't find any information on the C# side.
